# PHP File Upload using url parameters

Tags: php, file, url, upload

Is there a way to upload a file to server using php and the filename in a parameter (instead using a submit form), something like this:

> **myserver/upload.php?file=c:\example.txt**

Im using a local server, so i dont have problems with filesize limit or upload function, and i have a code to upload file using a form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload:
    <table>
      <tr><td><input name="upfile" type="file"></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload"></td></tr>
    </table>  
  </form>
<?php    
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){

    // Define the upload location
    $target_path = "c:\\";

    // Create the file name with path
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['upfile']['name']); 

    // Try to move the file from the temporay directory to the defined.
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['upfile']['name']). 
             " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
?>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: @prasanna You should move your comment to an answer. Gets my upvote :)

Comment: If the client and the server are on the same machine, this is possible. Otherwise, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
Image Upload Via url:
//check
$url = "http://theonlytutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/blog-logo1.png";
$name = basename($url);
try {
    $files = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($files) {
        $stored_name = time() . $name;
        file_put_contents("assets/images/product/$stored_name", $files);
    }
}catch (Exception $e){
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing this localy do you have the need to use "upload" mechanisms? otherwise if you're sending something externaly you could use cURL to upload the file, and run the PHP script on the CLI, quick google: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use url to send the name of the file like below:

```
www.website.com/upload.php?hilton_plaza_party.jpg
```

There is a script to do that. Here: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/